# Is there a way to automatically generate objects in a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a model that generates 100 code automatically as a task

Answer (score 0):

**Django inspectdb command**

Once you have set up the database connection in Django, you can auto-generate the models. Yes you heard it correctly! Django provides a utility to auto-generate models from an existing database via inspectdb command.

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/)